# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get an error when I try to display data based on $ nip in the model, how can I get $ nip data when I press the view button

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError
Message: Too few arguments to function Berkas_model::getPengajuanKG(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\pkl\application\controllers\Data.php on line 419 and exactly 1 expected
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\pkl\application\models\Berkas_model.php
Line Number: 125

Here's the code inline number 125

```
public function getPengajuanKG($nip)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_berkas` WHERE `id_jenis_berkas` = 'KP1' OR `id_jenis_berkas` = 'SK1' OR `id_jenis_berkas` = 'SK2' AND `nip` = '$nip' ";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```

In Controller

```
public function cetak_kp()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Kenaikan Pangkat';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('tbl_user', ['nip' => $this->session->userdata('nip')])->row_array();

    $data['pengajuan'] = $this->berkas_model->getPengajuanKG();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('approve/cetak_kp', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And in view when I clicked view button

```
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?= $i; ?></th>
<td><?= $b['nip']; ?></td><td>
<?= $b['nama_pegawai']; ?></td>
<td><?= tanggal('d F Y', $b['tanggal_pengajuan']); ?></td>
<td align="center">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('data/cetak_kp/' . $b['nip']) ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have method declaration:

```
public function getPengajuanKG($nip)
```

which accept 1 argument. Here you call that method without arguments:

```
$data['pengajuan'] = $this->berkas_model->getPengajuanKG();
```

you should add argument to you method:

```
$nip = 'something you need to assign to this variable';
$data['pengajuan'] = $this->berkas_model->getPengajuanKG($nip);
```